# VNC Server not responsive after a few days

Tags: 11.10, server, vnc

I am new to Ubuntu (11.10) - I installed Ubuntu on a box which has no screen and no keyboard. It is mostly used as a file and media server (i.e. samba + XBMC) and I control it via tightvncserver.
So far so good: I can connect via VNC and view / control the screen remotely.

But after a few days, when trying to connect via VNC, I don't get a response. The media server is still on, ping is fine, but VNC is down. The only solution I have found is to plug a screen and keyboard and reboot. All is then fine but the problem arises again after a few days...

I am not sure how to diagnose the problem (maybe some log files?) or if this is just a configuration issue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you reboot the server

Comment: Rebooting solves the issue temporarily but it arises again after a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer but here is what I've done for this problem: I have installed an SSH server so that I can remotely reboot the machine from another computer where I have installed an SSH client.

Not ideal, but it works.